# Magento 2 product export is not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.3.3, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5

I'm trying to export products in CSV via the default export feature.
The store has 40k+ products. If I add any filter to export and click the "continue" button - the export file creates, but if I try to export products without any filters(all products) it creates a file with name like importexport_5f64371q4486c and it always has 0 bytes... The issue exists only in the live environment, dev\local environments have a little delay and then it fills with the data, but in the live environment, this delay is permanent. Cron is working, I also tried to start exportProcessor - still 0 bytes. Queue message status is 3, and it's also permanent. Any ideas?

Comment: You can try to check your log files.

Comment: Log files are empty...

Comment: Share error files or screenshots

Answer (score 0):

you can try this cmd

php bin/magento cron:run

php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor